# how to detect immutable field changes with helm before upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubernetes-helm, gcp

We have pipelines to do some deployments in GCP. Underneath our pipeline uses helm apply/upgrade and sometimes it fails when our users try to change immutable helm fields. For example [`transitEncryptionMode`](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/redis/redisinstance#schema) is an immutable field meaning once set it cannot change. So if our users try to change it `helm upgrade` fails and runs a roll-back due to atomic flag used.

We would like to detect immutable field changes earlier before running a `helm upgrade`. If we could do that then we would avoid failure in apply and an extra roll-back operation. We tried to achieve this by `helm upgrade --dry-run=server` it doesn't detect immutable field changes.

So is there a way to identify immutable fields changes before running `helm upgrade`? Thanks.